# fatal: division by zero attempted in multicolum two files

Tags: awk

I am attempting to do some division on two dat files using awk command.
But I encounter below error

awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=72721) fatal: division by zero attempted

The code I used is here

```
paste Bcase1.dat Ecase1.dat | awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $4/$34, $8/$38, $12/$42}' > results.dat
```

My files are attached here

https:Xt-vpB8hpSYnh

Please replace X with //we.tl/  in above link (otherwise I could not post it so I did like that).

ideally output data file " results.dat" should have data range upto 1.64205 but after error it stops at 1.33355 and after this number (corresponds to 1st column) the sript stops.

If there is any simple workaround, please help me. I would be grateful for uou.

Comment: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Dear Cyrus, I need a code that can do my the job what I wanted to do with my script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the error message tells you what the problem is: in line 72721 a division by zero occurs.
You should check this by an if-else-condition:

```
paste Bcase1.dat Ecase1.dat | awk '{print $1, $2, $3, (($34 == 0) ? "NaN" : $4/$34), ($38 == 0) ? "NaN" : $8/$38, ($42 == 0) ? "NaN" : $12/$42}'
```

For line 72721, this will give you

```
1.33405 10.0000 -0.00112531 NaN NaN NaN
```

Please note that there are roughly 14 lines with 'division by zero'.

Comment: Dear F. Knorr, Thanks for the answering my query.  I will get back to you if I face any error.  I check the NaN error and replaced this NaN error with 0.000 using sed command in next step.

Comment: @astha wouldn't it make more sense to simply insert 0.000 in the awk script rather than inserting NaN in the awk script and then piping it to sed to change every NaN to 0.000?

Comment: Dear @EdMorton I do not think so. Because before using the script it will again produce the fatal error and I do not want NaN in my final data.

Comment: @astha : What Ed Morton means is, couldn't you simply run
paste Bcase1.dat Ecase1.dat | awk '{print $1, $2, $3, (($34 == 0) ? "0.000" : $4/$34), ($38 == 0) ? "0.000" : $8/$38, ($42 == 0) ? "0.000" : $12/$42}'

Comment: @F.Knorr ohh, I am sorry I could not get it. Thank you very much. I got it now.